# "AnonymousModel" Embedded Models in "Application Model" with Push Component and Postgre

Tags: push-notification, loopbackjs

How is it possible to use the Application Model with APNS settings and Postgre.

The Application Models has embedded Models. 
I'm right that in tranditional databases the embedded models are simply saved as object?
The String field of pushsettings has a varchar(1024).

The Push Example does this:

```
pushSettings: {
 apns: {
   certData: config.push.apnsCertData,
   keyData: config.push.apnsKeyData,
   feedbackOptions: {
     batchFeedback: true,
     interval: 300
   }
 },
 gcm: {
    serverApiKey: config.push.gcmServerApiKey
      }
 }
}
```

the certData and keyData are to long for the 1024 chars.

So how to use this correct with Postgres?

Right now the only thing I see is to extend the application model and set the pushSettings field to a larger value, but I am not able to get this work too.

Please Please help me

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mananged to get it work like I thought in first place.
The extended application Model json:

```
{
"name": "application",
"base": "Application",
"properties": {

"pushSettings": {
  "postgresql": {
    "dataType": "text",
    "dataLength": null,
    "nullable": "YES"
  },
  "apns": {
    "production": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "description": [
        "Production or development mode. It denotes what default APNS",
        "servers to be used to send notifications.",
        "See API documentation for more details."
      ]
    },

    "certData": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The certificate data loaded from the cert.pem file"
    },
    "keyData": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The key data loaded from the key.pem file"
    },

    "pushOptions": {
      "type": {
        "gateway": "string",
        "port": "number"
      }
    },

    "feedbackOptions": {
      "type": {
        "gateway": "string",
        "port": "number",
        "batchFeedback": "boolean",
        "interval": "number"
      }
    }
  },
  "gcm": {
    "serverApiKey": "string"
  }
}
```